# Regular expression which accept other language

Tags: java, regex, utf-8

Sorry guys,Im a novice, Im reframing my question.I have one regular expression `[A-Za-z0-9._]*[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9._]*` which accepts alphabets alone,alphanumerics but not numerics alone, and special characters allowed are .(dot) and (underscore).

Valid entries are

1. ABC123de (alphanumeric- irrespective of the case)
2. ABCDEfgh (only alphabets – irrespective of the case)
3. Abc.123 (only special characters allowed are _ and .)

**It is accepting the above requirement**.

However If I enter characters like `ààâüüúúàççé`, it is not accepting. Then one friend gave this `[\p{L}\d._]*\p{L}+[\p{L}\d._]*` which is not working. Make I know whether we need to modify `[\p{L}\d._]*\p{L}+[\p{L}\d._]*` to accept `ààâüüúúàççé`.

Comment: Do you have UTF-8 support in all the layers of your application

Comment: Hi Rohit, for this username validation, Im not using UT8-support.

Comment: If you are not using UTF8, how are the users entering characters like "ààâüüúúàççé" in their user name in the first place? What encoding _are_ you using?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
"ààâüüúúàççé".matches( "^[\\p{L}\\d._]*\\p{L}+[\\p{L}\\d._]*$" ); // true
```